# Group by sum with date and two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, group-by

The following extracts of two tables are given (Oracle SQL):

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
|  Orders  |            |             |
+----------+------------+-------------+
| Order ID | Date       | Customer ID |
| 12345    | 12.05.2018 | 456         |
| 12346    | 01.09.2021 | 646         |
| 12347    | 03.03.2019 | 836         |
| 12348    | 04.06.2020 | 1026        |
| 12349    | 05.07.2020 | 1216        |
| 12350    | 04.01.2020 | 1406        |
+----------+------------+-------------+

+-------------+----------+
|   Country   |          |
+-------------+----------+
| Customer ID | Country  |
| 1026        | GB       |
| 836         | USA      |
| 1026        | Germany  |
| 2166        | USA      |
| 2546        | GB       |
| 4154        | France   |
+-------------+----------+
```

The desired outcome should provide lines with Order ID, Date, Customer ID, Country as well as:

1. The amount of orders by the customer of a certain order ID over the last 10 and 30 days
2. The amount of orders by the country of a certain customer over the last 10 and 30 days

Since every customer belongs to a country the aggregated amounty by country are always at least as high as by a customer.

So the result should look like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Desired Outcome (Results fictitious) |            |             |            |                                     |                                     |                                    |                                    |
+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Order ID                             | Date       | Customer ID | Country ID | Amount Orders Cutsomer Last 10 Days | Amount Orders Cutsomer Last 30 Days | Amount Orders Country Last 10 Days | Amount Orders Country Last 30 Days |
| 12347                                | 03.03.2019 | 836         | USA        | 7                                   | 15                                  | 124                                | 578                                |
+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why is it so hard to post data as text ?

Comment: Sorry I am not very familiar yet with the options. The picture was the default option. As text it was very illegible.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: I changed the format.

Comment: Can you also show us the expected result as formatted text? (I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: The expected results is now also adapted.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not clearly stated but I think you are asking for a list of every order within last 30 days and a summary count by Customer and Country for within 10 and within 30 days.

In a CTE/SubQuery
Join the two table together using customer ID
add logical columns for order within 10 days, order within 30 days. These should return true = 1, false = 0

```
    Select from CTE, 
    use 
    SUM(Within10) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID),
    SUM(Within30) OVER(PARTITION BY CountryCode),
    SUM(Within10) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID),
    SUM(Within30) OVER(PARTITION BY CountryCode),
```

This is T-SQL so the syntax for PL/SQL may vary slightly

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to get the results described on a order basis for a random number of 10 orders, i.e. the amount of orders by the customer of a certain order ID over the last 10 and 30 days and the amount of orders by the country of a certain customer over the last 10 and 30 days.

Comment: In which case you will need to do them as co-related sub-queries.
````
    Select OrderID

Comment: Can you show me how these  co-related sub-queries should be written?

Comment: In which case you will need to do them as co-related sub-queries.
Select 
       O.OrderID
       ,O.Date
       ,O.CustomerID
       ,C.Country
      ,(SELECT
               COUNT(OxOrderID)
        FROM
                Orders AS Ox
        WHERE
                 Ox.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
            AND
                  Ox.Date > DATEADD(DAY,-10,GETDATE())
       ) AS [Amount Orders Customer Last 10 Days]
FROM
        Orders AS O
JOIN
        Customers AS C ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID

You may be better off leaving this to the reporting layer.

Comment: With this code I am getting the error: "Right parenthesis is missing"

Comment: at a closing parenthasis after the = O.CustomerID to close out the SELECT sub-query.
If you were not able to work this out for yourself, please don't run code you got off the internet without having it reviewed by a peer first.